# How can we set parameters and variables in repositories?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

This is just a sample structure. But I want to fetch data from parameters and variables. How can we do it so that I can reuse this for all the repositories (doing it for 50 repositories)?

```
    resources:
      repositories:
      - repository: {parameter}
        type: git
        name: ${parameter}
        ref: $(BranchName)
        trigger:
          - Develop
          - Release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that set parameter and variable is not supported in repositories resources.

Currently we are only able to use the parameter or variable for `ref` here. It's not supported for the `repository` and `name`. See [resources.repositories.repository definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines) for details.
[image]

As a work around, we can add all the repositories as resources, and then set parameter and variable at the checkout step. Reference [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops).

For example:

```
parameters:
- name: repository
  type: string
  default: myRepo1
  values:
  - myRepo1
  - myRepo2
  - myRepo3
- name: reponame
  type: string
  default: myReponame1
  values:
  - myReponame1
  - myReponame2

variables:
  BranchName : main


resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: myRepo1
    type: git
    name: myReponame1
    ref: $(BranchName)
    trigger:
      - Develop
      - Release
  - repository: myRepo2
    type: git
    name: myReponame2
    ref: $(BranchName)
    trigger:
      - Develop
      - Release
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: ${{parameters.repository}}
```

However, the requirement makes sense, you could create a suggestion ticket via: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem)